# MySQL WorkBench EER model not show PK

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I can't find that in the settings. Where I can set that in table will show primary keys (PK) like it is showing foreign keys (FK).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the (PK) addendum is currently not possible. Better switch to `Workbench (Default)` object notation (see menu Model). There primary and foreign keys have their own icon.